# "When an helicopter flies over your head and you're supposed to be in the middle of the sea its not real"

Tags: meaning

An actor in this [video](https://youtu.be/OI-4VA8ZqAA?t=1m26s) says "When a helicopter flies over your head, and you're supposed to be in the middle of the sea, it's not real".

What does that mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about english Language and Usage as define in the Help Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is from a set of bloopers from *Pirates of the Caribbean*.

The blooper is that the setting of the movie appears to be at a time before helicopters were invented, yet the actor probably saw a helicopter flying above him. The scene was filmed from a helicopter.

So, the quote refers to the actor seeing a helicopter. That breaks his concentration as an actor. He is trying to act as if in an era before helicopters, but there is one right above him.

Comment: Uh, wouldn't the presence of a movie camera have already shattered the illusion of being in the 18th century?

Comment: @HotLicks I think sometimes actors just get distracted by silly things and come crashing out of character. The actor probably saw a helicopter (maybe with Mickey Mouse painted on the side) and he just could no longer act as if he were a pirate. Now, if an actor can't act if he sees a camera then he'd need to go to Broadway.

Comment: now that makes sense :)